# Json and java conversion

Tags: java, json, gson

Below is piece of my java code

```
Type relMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String,   Map<String ,Map<String, List<Set<ProfileData>>>>>>>(){}.getType();
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("D:\\work.json");
    String jsonTxt;
    try {
        jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
        System.out.println(jsonTxt);
        JSONObject jsons = new JSONObject(jsonTxt); 
        String jString= gson.toJson(jsons);
            gson.fromJson(jString, relMapType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Below is my json data in "work.json" file

```
{
   "string1":{
      "string2":{
         "string3":{
            "string4":[
               {
                  "primaryKey":{
                     "projectCode":"PC",
                     "type":"type1",
                     "code1":"data1",
                     "code2":"data2"
                  },
                  "status":"status1",
                  "Id":"123",
                  "frequency":"freq",
                  "destFre":"destFreq"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

when I run the code getting below exception. Can anyone help me?

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 5 column 21
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:806)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:761)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:710)
at com.JsonExample.main(JsonExample.java:97)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 5 column 21

Comment: I'm guessing that `List<Set<ProfileData>>` isn't right

Comment: Construct such object programatically and then `gson.toGson`. You'll see how the json should look like

Comment: @xenteros .Why you down vote this question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `Set` within a `List` in `List<Set<ProfileData>>`. Both are `Collection`s and will therefore be treated as arrays. The same part of your JSON is an array of objects. Remove `Set` or `List` and it should work.

Comment: Can you explain the issue over here please. I dint get the correct point what you said.

Comment: Since `Set` and `List` are both `Collection`s the decoder expected to find `"string4": [[{...}]]` and your JSON contained `"string4": [{...}]`.